# Why does updating an object more than once throw a tracking error?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

I am writing an application using Blazor that interacts with a SQL Server database to implement basic CRUD functions (create, read, update, delete) on the database, using Entity Framework Core.

My goal is to make a web application like a news board, where articles can be stored and videos attached to them.

When I go into the update screen, make my changes, and save them, they save like they should:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when I go back into the same article, edit it again, and save my changes again, I get a tracking error, and my changes are not saved:

[image]

How do I remove the duplicate tracking that is going on?

I have confirmed:

- I am using scoped rather than singleton on my service
- Each get call on the database has `.AsNoTracking()` on it
- The input ids are different for each input field

I am showing my code below. Please comment if there is anything else I should add

`Pages/ArticleEdit.razor`:

```
@page "/article/edit/{ArticleId:int}"

@using EntitySQL.Data
@using EntitySQL.Models
@using EntitySQL.Services

@inject NewsServices Service
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<PageTitle>Edit Article</PageTitle>

@if (@ArticleId == -1) {
    <p>There is no article with that given id!</p>
} else {
    <h1>Edit "@name"</h1>
    
    <div class="grid-container-2">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" @bind-value="@name">
        <label for="story">Story:</label>
        <textarea id="story" rows="12" @bind="@story"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gap"/>
    
    <div class="grid-container-3">
        
        @for(int i = 0; i < videoList.Count; i++){
            int index = i;
            <section>
                <p>Video @(index + 1):</p>
                <label for="@("vname" + index)">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="@("vname" + index)" @bind-value="@videoList[@index].Name">
                <label for="@("vlink" + index)">Link:</label>
                <input type="text" id="@("vlink" + index)" @bind-value="@videoList[@index].Link">
            </section>
        }
    </div>
    
    <div class="gap"/>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="@(() => Submit())">Save changes!</button>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    string name;
    string story;
    List<Video> videoList;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    {
        Article article = Service.GetArticle(ArticleId);
        name = article.Name;
        story = string.Join(Constants.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, article.Paragraphs);
        
        // The below feature adds extra videos into it
        /*
        List<Video> videos = article.Videos?.ToList();
        videoList = Enumerable.Repeat(new Video {Name = "", Link = ""}, Constants.MAX_VIDEOS).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < videos.Count; i++)
        {
            Video video = videos[i];
            videoList[i] = video;
        }
        */

        videoList = article.Videos?.ToList();
    }
    
    public void Submit()
    {
        ICollection<String> paragraphs = story.Split(Constants.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        Service.UpdateArticle(ArticleId, name, paragraphs, videoList);
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"/article/read/{ArticleId}");
    }
}
```

`Pages/ArticleRead.razor`:

```
@page "/article/read/{ArticleId:int}"

@using EntitySQL.Models
@using EntitySQL.Services

@inject NewsServices Service

<PageTitle>Read Article</PageTitle>

@if(@ArticleId == -1)
{
    <p>There is no article with that given id!</p>
} 
else
{
    <h1>@article.Name</h1>
    <a href="/article/edit/@ArticleId">Edit this article</a>
    
    @foreach (string paragraph in @article.Paragraphs)
    {
            <p>@paragraph</p>
    }
    
    <section class="grid-container">
        @foreach (Video video in @article.Videos)
        {
            <figure>
                    <h2>@video.Name</h2>
                    <a href="@video.Link">@video.Link</a>
                </figure>
        }
    </section>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    Article article;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        article = Service.GetArticle(ArticleId);
    }
}
```

`NewsServices.cs`:

```
using EntitySQL.Data;
using EntitySQL.Models;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EntitySQL.Services;

public class NewsServices
{
    private readonly NewsContext context;
    
    /*
     * Get an instance of Services
     */
    public NewsServices(NewsContext con)
    {
        context = con;
    }
    
    /*
     * Get the list of all of the articles in the database
     */
    public ICollection<Article> GetAllArticles()
    {
        return context.Articles
            .Include(a => a.Videos)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
    }
    
    /**
     * Add an article to the database
     */
    public int AddArticle(Article article)
    {
        if (article.Name.Length == 0 || article.Paragraphs.Count == 0)
        {
            return Constants.INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }

        context.Articles.Add(article);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return 0;
    }
    
    /*
     * Get an article from the database
     */
    public Article GetArticle(int Id)
    {
        return context.Articles
            .Include(a => a.Videos)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);
    }
    
    /**
     * Update an article in the database
     */
    public int UpdateArticle(int Id, string Name, ICollection<String> Paragraphs, ICollection<Video>? Videos)
    {
        Article article = context.Articles.Find(Id);

        if (article == null)
        {
            return Constants.INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        } 
        
        article.Name = Name;
        article.Paragraphs = Paragraphs;
        article.Videos = Videos;

        context.SaveChanges();

        return 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Delete an article from the database
     */
    public int DeleteArticle(int Id)
    {
        Article article = context.Articles.Find(Id);

        if (article == null) 
        {
            return Constants.INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
        
        context.Articles.Remove(article);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Add a video to the database
     */
    public int AddVideo(string Name, string Link)
    {
        if (Name.Length + Link.Length == 0) //On x86 processors, adding the two and then comparing is probably faster than doing two comparisons
        {
            return Constants.INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }

        context.Videos.Add(new Video
                               {
                                   Name = Name,
                                   Link = Link
                               });
        context.SaveChanges();

        return 0;
    }
    
    /*
     * Get a video from the database
     */
    public Video GetVideo(int Id)
    {
        return context.Videos
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);
    }
    
    /**
     * Delete a video from the database
     */
    public int DeleteVideo(int Id)
    {
        Video video = context.Videos.Find(Id);

        if (video == null)
        {
            return Constants.INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
        
        context.Videos.Remove(video);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: For reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0 (at my work we use a context factory at a more granular level as described in this article - creating a context in each method where a CRUD operation is performed, using a context factory).

Comment: Also noting this important point from EF overview docs: *The lifetime of a DbContext begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is disposed. A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of a DbContext instance is usually very short.* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Comment: Also for reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Blazor (server) the lifetime scope will generally be the session rather than the request, so passing entities around is a bit different than a web application which deserializes copies during POST, where in Blazor it will be maintaining state on the server.

This means that when you call code like:

```
context.Videos.Add(new Video
{
    Name = Name,
    Link = Link
});
```

or

```
context.Videos.Update(video);
```

These operations will cause the DbContext to start tracking that entity. This will interfere will future calls to Update an entity, even though you read that entity instance /w `AsNoTracking()` which will give you an untracked copy read from the DB, when you go to save that untracked instance the DbContext is still tracking the instance you added / last updated. The simplest fix is wherever you call `Add` or `Update` (or `Attach`), detach that instance when you are done.

```
var newVideo = new Video
{
    Name = Name,
    Link = Link
});
context.Videos.Add(newVideo);
context.SaveChanges()
context.Entry(newVideo).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

.. and ...

```
context.Videos.Update(video);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Entry(video).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

This will prevent the change tracker reference from messing up with previously attached references.

Comment: For people who might look at this later, to solve my problem I had to add a foreach statement for each video in article.Videos, and change the EntityState of each video in the article object to be detached. Still marking this answer as accepted because it explained the issue clearly and showed me how to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Adopt a unit of work approach. The `DbContext` is light weight. Here I use a factory and configure the DbContext for NoTracking as well as the new EF 8 feature `Optimize-DbContext -OutputDir SomeFolder`

`Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
{
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseModel(ApplicationDbContextModel.Instance);
});
```

Note the `UseModel` usage wich improves perfomance by preventing the model construction when instancing a new DbContext.

Example of a UpdateMethod :

`StorageBroker.cs`

```cs
public partial class StorageBroker(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory) : IStorageBroker
{

private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;

public async ValueTask<Message> UpdateMessageAsync(Message message)
{
    using ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = await this.dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    EntityEntry<Message> result = applicationDbContext.Messages.Update(message);
    await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result.Entity;
}
```

Note: My Broker is consumed by a service all the error trapping validation etc is there.